# How to create a dictionary mapping to set of values to avoid identical keys in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have the following dictionary that maps a word to the frequency with which that word appears in a text:

```
{'loves' : 3, 'coding' : 3}
```

words 'loves' and 'coding' both appeared 3 times in the text and thus have the same value. Now we know that if we want to swap keys and values in this dictionary, it will return this:

either

```
{3:'loves'}
```

or this

```
{3:'coding'}
```

because identical keys are not allowed in a dictionary

Now my question is how do I swap the keys and features in the dictionary while avoiding duplicate keys as follows:

```
{3: {'loves', 'coding'}}
```

This is my failed attempt:

```
def func(text, words): 

d = dict()

for word in text.split():
    if word in words:

        if word in d:
            d[word] += 1 

        elif word not in d:
            d[word] = 1

# return d


newDict = dict()

for key in d:
    newKey = d[key]
    newDict[newKey] = set()


    newDict[newKey].add(key)


return newDict
```

## Edit :

Thanks for all your valuable answers. I also got mine to work by fixing the following bug: a comment is added next to the buggy line

```
# swapping keys and values in a dictionary:
newDict = dict()

def func(text, words):

    d = dict()

    for word in text.split():
       if word in words:

          if word in d:
              d[word] += 1 

          elif word not in d:
             d[word] = 1

# return d


newDict = dict()

for key in d:

    if d[key] not in newDict:
        newDict[d[key]] = set({key})  # This was my bug. Initially I had 
                                      # newDict[d[key]] = set()

    elif d[key] in newDict:
        newDict[d[key]].add(key)



return newDict
```

Now if I run it on the following input:

```
func('Ahmed loves loves coding coding is rewarding', {'loves', 'coding', 'I'})
```

I get this which is exactly what I wanted:

```
{2: {'coding', 'loves'}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

> words 'loves' and 'coding' both appeared 3 times in the text and thus have the same key.

they actually have the same *value*, not the same key (maybe you mistyped it?).

But you can just do a simple `for`-loop followed by a simple logic where you check first if the value exist in your new `dict`; it it does, append to their value; if it doesn't, create a new entry.

```
d = {'loves' : 3, 'coding' : 3} 
new_dict = {}

for key, value in d.items():
    if new_dict.get(value, None):
        new_dict[value].add(key)
    else:
        new_dict[value] = {key}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in @RafaelC's answer, only using sets:

```
d = {'loves' : 3, 'coding' : 3} 
new_dict = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    if value not in new_dict:
        new_dict[value].add(key)
    else:
        new_dict[value] = {key}
```

Comment: My answer uses `set` :}. I had edited it right after I posted

Comment: You could use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) as a alternative.